# Mac OS X Kernel Extension CPU Selection

Tags: kernel, kernel-module, mach

I was reading the source code for the model-specific register (MSR) driver kernel extension that ships with the Intel Performance Counter Monitor (http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-performance-counter-monitor-a-better-way-to-measure-cpu-utilization). Since independent copies of the MSRs/performance counters are stored on different CPUs, it is necessary to specify which CPU to read from. This is done by calling the **mp_rendezvous_no_intrs** function.

```
mp_rendezvous_no_intrs(cpuReadMSR, (void*)idatas);
```

This causes each processor the check if it is the correct processor number, and if so read the data from the MSR:

```
void cpuReadMSR(void* pIData){
    pcm_msr_data_t* data = (pcm_msr_data_t*)pIData;
    volatile uint cpu = cpu_number();
    if(data->cpu_num == cpu)
    {
        data->value = RDMSR(data->msr_num);
    }
}
```

My question is: is turning off interrupts (via however mp_rendezvous_no_intrs does it) enough to cause the thread running the cpuReadMSR function to stay on the same CPU the whole time? If it is not, I worry about the following failure scenario:

1. The cpu reads its numerical id with cpu_number(), decides that it is the correct CPU, and starts to read the MSR.
2. The thread is preempted by the scheduler and moved to a different CPU.
3. The MSR is read, but now is read from a different CPU, thus giving the wrong value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Disabling interrupts disables ALL interrupts, not just some of them. This includes the timer interrupt, which is what normally allows a running thread to be preempted.

While interrupts are disabled, nothing (short of something crazy like a CPU exception) can *interrupt* your code from running, start to finish, on a single CPU.

Comment: That's kind-of theoretical these days ... as ordinary interrupt-routing/masking subsystems (the [IO]APIC) can be programmed to create _any_ x86 _trap_ (that word specifically chosen ... any of the 256 interrupt _vectors_, 32 of which are _traps_, one of those explicitly named NMI - Non Maskable Interrupt). Disabling interrupts on CPU level (`cli` instruction) does not switch off traps, and therefore does not disable hardware interrupt dispatch to the 32 lower-numbered interrupt vectors, if the IOAPIC is configured such. In short: It's hard to "disable interrupts" on x86 CPUs these days.

Comment: To clarify a little ... the Operating System needs to help you with the task to "run this code [ on all cpus ] while no interrupts can happen". That's because doing so requires a complex setup - programming the APICs to block interrupts as well as doing CPU rendevous without inter-processor-interrupts, as well as masking all possible sources of NMIs.